# Create Separate UIwebViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, xcode6

I have two UIwebViews. I coded each one to go to a different webpage url. But both of them go to the first url (http://test.bithumor.co/test26.php)
 Here's the code from the view controller.m

```
//    
//  ViewController.m    
//  BitHumor    
//    
//  Created by danny rodriguez on 7/26/15.    
//  Copyright (c) 2015 BitDeveloping. All rights reserved.    
//    

#import "ViewController.h"



@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView2;




@end



@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {


    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];


    NSString *url=@"http://test.bithumor.co/test26.php";

    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];

    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];

    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];

    [self.view addSubview:webview];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIWebView *webview2=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    NSString *url2=@"http://google.com";
    NSURL *nsurl2=[NSURL URLWithString:url2];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl2];
    [webview2 loadRequest:nsrequest2];

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

@end
```

Both web views are linked to the @property, how do I make each of them go to their designated webpage urls? (Please tell me step by step, as I am new to Objective-C coding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you already created `IBOutlets` for `UIWebViews` make sure to define them as `weak`, you defined one of them as `Strong` and other one as `weak`, the mistake that you have did is creating third `UIWebView` that you have added as `subview`. This will cover whole view above your two uiwebviews.

```
     //Not required, remove this code 
     UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
     [self.view addSubview:webview];
```

Now just create two requests and load them to `UIWebViews`

```
      //For webview 1
      NSString *url=@"http://test.bithumor.co/test26.php";
      NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
      NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
      [self.webView loadRequest:nsrequest];

      //For webview 2
      NSString *url2=@"http://google.com";
      NSURL *nsurl2=[NSURL URLWithString:url2];
      NSURLRequest *nsrequest2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl2];
      [self.webView2 loadRequest:nsrequest2];
```

Comment: [webview2 loadRequest:nsrequest2]; I got an error "Use of undeclared identifier 'webview2': did you mean 'webview'?'"

Comment: use webView and webView2 edited my answer and remove this code  [self.view addSubview:webview];

Comment: What do you mean by use webView and WebView 2? I already removed: [self.view addSubview:webview]; Here's what it looks like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1JMd6.png

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView2; 
you have defined this property, you should not get this error then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86817/discussion-between-prasad-and-php-web-dev-101).